# angular cdk drag and drop all events stoped working all of sudden in between drag and drops

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular-cdk-drag-drop

created a card game named durak with cdk drag and drop and Firestore its working fine but in some cases if any opponent player made any changes in the Firestore document and the primary player is dragging any card in that moment then all the events stoped working .

i do have to create 2d slots for the table it might have the case why these drag and drop stoped workig . i don't know why its stucking

at first i thought all these conditions in predicate or in the drop method are stucking all these events but its not.

Comment: check your console if errors

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EMq6PvEyfSli0RE2cuq8gOKLZYqkTjqF/view?usp=sharing


this is the video link where in the second round primary player in this video is attacker he can drop multiple cards in the table while he is draging second card and wants to drop it in the table but at that same moment if opponent player defend that first card and updated firestore document then all the primary player's cards are re-eterating in the ui and after this etration all the events related to this drag and drop library are being stucked . idk why?